# Can I use logistic regression to check if my groups are comparable?

Tags: regression, logistic, group-differences

I want to compare if my participants are similar in some categorical variables (e.g., sex, race) and continuous variables (age and some cognitive measures). It is a 2x2 design, language group (bilingual vs. monolingual) and diagnostic group (desease  vs. healthy).

Ideally, the above-mentioned factors should be controlled that's why I need to compare. While normal ways are to run ANOVAs and Chi-Square tests, can I do 2 logistic regressions with (1) language group as DV and put all the other as IVs and (2) diagnostic group as DV?

That seems not to solve the question of whether there are interactions between groups, so I have to do subsequent ANOVAs putting continuous variables as IVs?

I am finding the most efficient and correct way to doit. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do a multivariate test to detect any differences between the two group with respect to any of the independent variables, by switching the roles of independent and dependent variables as originally suggested by Peter O'Brien.  This approach is described [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/lrm.html).  If you can't at all predict which group you're in, there are not group differences in the (temporary) predictors.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies! Then I have to do ANOVAs if I want to see if there are interactions when IVs are continuous (e.g., age) between 2 types of groups?

Comment: Do an overall chunk test with multiple degrees of freedom (likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test or Wald test).  Interactions add a lot of parameters.  Used e.g. to see if group differences in proportion of males depends on another variable.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions! I am gonna explore it further!

Comment: Note that on this site thanks is expressed by clicking the "up" symbol.